# Minimal 18.04 server with uefi boot

Tags: server, ubuntu-minimal

I am exploring options for a hardened server. I want uefi boot. I was wondering about taking the list of packages on the minimal instal and then removing all the packages on the full server that are not in the minimal install. Would that work or am I missing something?

TIA

Paul

Answer (score 1):

The [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#mini_system_in_UEFI_mode) has even easier instructions on how to create a minimal server with UEFI boot.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is certainly a better starting point. The hardware and os are being supplied by a hosting provider so it will be standard ubuntu server. We plan to run ansible scripts to configure it. My proposed method is to use python to generate the sensible script that removes everything.